# Adding methods to base ruby class in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a very simple module, `Utility`, defined in `utility.rb` in the lib directory of a rails app. It just adds two simple methods to classes from Ruby standard library.

However, when I `require` this file, the classes inside it don't respond to the methods I have defined here. Such as, `[].concat_with` fails with a `NoMethodError`. Why?

```
module Utility

  #
  # This module just contains useful functions
  #

  class Array
    def concat_with(seperator = "")
      reject! { |c| c.empty? }.join(seperator)
    end
  end

  class Float
    def flat
      "%gx" % (self / 100.00)
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because you've defined new classes, instead of patching existing ones. These classes are `Utility::Array` and `Utility::Float`. In `module`-clause everything is in the module's scope.

In Ruby 2.0 [*refinements*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) were added that allow for temporary patches to existing classes, which seems like your case:

```
module Utility

  #
  # This module just contains useful functions
  #

  refine Array do
    def concat_with(seperator = "")
      reject! { |c| c.empty? }.join(seperator)
    end
  end

  refine Float do
    def flat
      "%gx" % (self / 100.00)
    end
  end

end
```

Then you do:

```
using Utility # Obviously, it has to be `required`
puts 3.14.flat
```

And these methods will only exist in the current scope. Once you go outside, they will vanish.

Of course, you can reference classes from outside the module, like so:

```
module Utility

  #
  # This module just contains useful functions
  #

  class ::Array
    def concat_with(seperator = "")
      reject! { |c| c.empty? }.join(seperator)
    end
  end

  class ::Float
    def flat
      "%gx" % (self / 100.00)
    end
  end

end
```

But that would write the changes permanently (process-wise). Sometimes that might be desirable, but I avoid this unless absolutely necessary, as it can easily conflict with changes made by other libraries.